# server terminated abnormally while linked server connection

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, linked-server

After several day successful connection with SQL Server and postgres now getting below error for some of the queries.

OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "PO" returned message "server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log for related messages. A stack dump indicates the PostgreSQL ODBC driver misbehaved and SQL Server terminated the connection as a result.

Comment: small data sets are retrieving issue exist for large data tables

Comment: Check the PostgreSQL log files.